# What would be a better way to visualise hazards on a map

Tags: maps, iot

I'm designing for map dashboard where users can monitor zones at factory sites. I'm introducing an icon to show when zones at these sites contain hazards (such as heat).

When users are performing a task in a zone, the user and task blobs combine. This is still acceptable. I use the same logic of combining blobs when a user is in the same zone as a hazard or when there's a hazard nearby a task. but it gets complicated when users are performing a task in a zone.

Is there a better way to visually show this instead of trying to combine 3 icons? **This is also the most crucial scenario as the user is in a zone performing a task where there's a potential hazard.**

I also need to consider sites where there are many zones nearby. As the map currently has no zoom function, there would be overcrowding if this scenario happens in multiple zones that are next to each other at the same time.

[image]

When blobs are placed on the map
[[image]][2

Comment: Are there both hazards in zones and hazardous tasks? Is there a distinction between the two? How is the zone graphically represented?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles the hazards for this are more environmental and are not related to the tasks-related hazards. There's no graphical separation between each of the zones.

Comment: I see the hazard blob on the map. Do the user and task blobs appear on the same map? Do they appear anywhere else, such as a list or other page?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes, the users and tasks on-site appear on the same map too. there's also a user list that displays all users that are on and off the site

Comment: My first thought was to mark the entire zone as hazardous then put the user and task blob in that zone. But your comment, "There's no graphical separation between each of the zones." seems to indicate that's not possible. — Do you see any problem combining the 3 blobs? — A different question, why the color blue for the hazard? Seems red/orange would communicate danger better.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles blue was used so as not to overwhelm the user if too many zones get triggered for high heat at the same time. While it is a hazard, at this point. there's no immediate need to take any action. e.g. factories will have some zones which are almost always hot. I'm considering using indigo or purple so it has at least a hint of red.

Comment: I think an example map, with various blobs, various hazards, and various zones, would help people get a better idea what you're looking for. You don't seem to like the idea but what does a map with the 3 combined blobs version look like? And, what did your map look like before?

Comment: Does the map show more than one user? Or does the user only see their own blob? Also, are there more than one task displayed for each user?

Comment: I don't see a response to this question: Do you see any problem combining the 3 blobs?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles the map shows multiple users, blobs and hazards. The map didnt have hazards before. so it showed users, tasks, and tasks with users. when there's more than 1 user or task. it would show a number inside the blob.

Comment: My question is asking if the hazard blob is intuitive, (and propose alternatives if its not) and in the scenario where there's a user doing a task when there's a hazard, is there a better way to visualize these 3 than combining the 3 blobs? combining 3 blobs takes a lot more space overall. and when there are smaller zones, there will be overcrowding of these blobs making it harder for the user to comprehend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the task, or if there's no task in the zone, mark the hazard:

[image: mark hazard]

Or mark the zone:

[image: mark zone]

Comment: thanks for the answer. marking the task works, but its not technically possible to mark the zone as i mentioned before

Comment: for your 1st solution, how would you show a zone that doesn't have a task?

Answer (score 0):

Many map applications, including Google maps, Waze, and Apple maps use icons to indicate a specific type of issue on the map. Such as a hazard, crash, lane closure, etc.

**In your instance, according to your post: the most crucial scenario is the combination of users and tasks in a hazard zone. I would create a separate icon for this specific use case (user+task+hazard). I would also design separate icons for the other possible combinations of user+hazard or task+hazard. This way you won't overcrowd the screen real estate.**

Here are some examples of different map applications using specific icons for each use case:

```
Apple map:
```

[image]

```
Google Map:
```

[image]

```
Waze map:
```

[image]